# put in bash or zsh history absolute path to files I working on

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, command-history

I have found that in bash i frequently use something like that:

- vim ./somefile1 less
- less ./dir1/dir2/somefile2
- cp some_other_relative_path_to_file

and so on

After that when I trying to find a command in history and run it I get an error because I am in a different directory now. Is it possible to configure bash to "expand" relative path to files with absolute one when they go to history?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to rewrite history so that when you run this:

```
ls
```

it gets saved as:

```
cd /current/directory && ls
```

For Bash there is a trick to modify its history, as explained in this great [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945288/saving-current-directory-to-bash-history). You'll need to use a Bash shell variable called `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

When set, its contents are executed every time before the prompt is shown. Setting it to this:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='hcmd=$(history 1); hcmd="${hcmd# *[0-9]*  }"; if [[ ${hcmd%% *} == "cd" ]]; then pwd=$OLDPWD; else pwd=$PWD; fi; hcmd=$(echo -e "cd $pwd && $hcmd"); history -s "$hcmd"'
```

will rewrite history as described above.

Try it first in a Terminal window and if you are happy with it, add it to your `.bashrc` file to enable it.

The downside is that, in its current incarnation, ***all*** commands will be prefixed with  `cd /some/dir`, which decreases readability and can get annoying for commands like `cd /usr/local`:

```
$ history | tail -n 5
  522  cd /Users/jaume && cd /usr/local
  523  cd /usr/local && file bin/ls
  524  cd /usr/local && cd ~
  525  cd /Users/jaume && file Documents/.localized 
  526  history | tail -n 5
```

You could of course modify `PROMPT_COMMAND` to only rewrite history for a reduced number of commands.