# Can I cycle through the history of shell commands that have only been used from current directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

So when using arrow up/down to cycle through prior commands, is there any way I can limit those to the commands used from the current directory? This would make my life 10 times easier...

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://github.com/tymm/directory-history

It's a plugin for zsh and does exactly what you want.

Remarks/Bug reports/Stars/... are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no such thing as a per-directory history in any of the shells I know. Your best bets are modifying some of the open sourced shells or hacking into hooks provided by `zsh` when running the `cd` command to load a new history. I'm pretty sure some zsh guru would find this a worthwile challenge.

Comment: Thanks, zsh looks promising for this, but I've never messed with it myself. Hopefully someone has an idea...

Answer (score 0):

zsh allows you to modify the entries that are stored in your history, it is easy to add a comment with the directory where you ran the command (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824051/saving-current-directory-to-zsh-history).

You just need to write a custom history search widget/function that will filter results based on `$PWD`.

Comment: [Put in bash or zsh history absolute path to files I am working on](http://superuser.com/questions/554212/put-in-bash-or-zsh-history-absolute-path-to-files-I-am-working-on) gives an example of how to do this in bash.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to mess around w/ this when I have time (which isn't now sadly). In the meantime, if someone can provide a ready-made answer, great =D

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell history extension that allows you to search history and shows you relevant results first based on the current directory, git repository, exit status, and host.

You can install the project here: https://github.com/curusarn/resh
Launch it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (replaces reverse search).
This is how the search application looks like:

[image: screenshot of the search application]

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the project and this is shame-less self-promotion

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: This is the *third* identical copy of the answer ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sorry about that. The questions are not quite the same but I think they are about the same underlying problem. I'm sharing the project because I think it can actually help people.